# Automapper many - to - many relationship

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a following Entity and Dto structure

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductProviders> ProductProviders { get; set; } = new HashSet<ProductProviders>();
}

public class ProductProviders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public Provider Provider { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new HashSet<Product>();
}

public class ProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ProductProvidersDto> Providers { get; set; }
}

public class ProductProvidersDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public ProviderDto Provider { get; set; }
    public ProductDto Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<ProductDto> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I am inserting an `Product` object into database, I would like for it to automatically insert corresponding records into `ProductProviders` table.

I have tried several sulutions from other posts here and some other sources, and last solution that I came up with was this-

```
CreateMap<ProductDto, Product>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.ProductProviders, opts => opts.MapFrom(r => r.Providers.Select(r => r.Provider.Id).ToList()));
```

But this is giving me back an error, saying that relation does not exist (but this is the closest one to success, I think).

To be clear:

1. DB relations are correct
2. All the necessary information is specified

Is there some way to fix this mapping, so that when I insert a `Product` into database, it also inserts records into `ProductProviders` table?

Comment: I suggest you to quit using automapper and create objects with **.Select** function from Linq

Comment: Do you have a mappingprofile for `ProductProvidersDto` and `ProductProviders`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AfterMap`(see: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html) and write there logic to assign/fill needed fields in your own way:

```
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
 {
   // write custom assignment logic etc.
 });
```